# Search XML with a LIKE or similar full search operation

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to search an XML valued column to see if a contains a string.  I don't know the schema, I want to know if the string is contained anywhere at all.  I don't know if XPATH would work in this situation.

The equivalent of

```
Select s.Name, ts.ValueXML from table t (nolock) 
join table2 ts (nolock) on t.key_Id = ts.key_Id
join table3 s (nolock) on ts.key_Id=s.key_Id
where s.Name like '%Lab%' and ts.ValueXML  like '%PreviewDateRange%'
```

> ERROR:  Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of like
>   function.

relevant `ts` Table columns

`ValueXml (XML(.), null)`

The item I'm searching for should be an attribute.  So if the above isn't possible, then anything containing that attribute would be a good alternative.

Comment: This should work. Could you show an example where it does not work?

Comment: Could you post the table definition, and tag the question with the type of RDBMS that you are using?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The simplest (but definitely not the fastest to execute) way would be to cast your column to `nvarchar(max)` before passing it to `like`:

```
cast(ValueXml as nvarchar(max)) like '%PreviewDateRange%'
```

Comment: This is a non-production, one off query.  Performance doesnt matter.  I tried this and got Error: Conversion of one or more characters from XML to target collation impossible

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey It should do the trick then - I tried it on [`sqlfiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/742c5/3), and it worked fine.

Comment: Edit required as the prose response mentions cast varchar and the code mentions nvarchar. Varchar is fine, but if a collation conversion is encountered nvarchar can be used - that was the part I needed.

Comment: This seems to search the XML tag names also. Any way to get rid of those?

Answer (score 3):

There you go:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyXmlMetadataColumn.exist('//*/text()[contains(upper-case(.),upper-case("MySearchTerm"))]') = 1
```

This seems to work fine for me and also does not search the XML tag names as the solution provided by  "dasblinkenlight".

I don't know how performant it is though.