# Query Xml from SQL using Entity Framework Database First

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, linq, entity-framework-6

I need to use Entity Framework, LINQ to query the XML data from the SQL in my asp.net mvc(C#) application.

I have a column `XMLValue` with data

```
<MetaData>
     <Reviews>1</Reviews>
     <Rating>1</Rating>
</MetaData>
```

I need to get all the `Customers` who have a `Rating` of 1 from the xml. I have referred to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1104689/111435) and I am not able to achieve it.

I have added the SQL function and added it to my edmx:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FilterCustomersByRating] 
    (@Rating int) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
    SELECT XMLTest.*
    FROM XMLTest
    CROSS APPLY XMLValue.nodes('//MetaData') N(C)
    where N.C.value('Rating[1]', 'int')=@Rating
GO
```

And the following DB function:

```
[DbFunction("XMLDBModel.Store", "FilterCustomersByRating")]
public static IQueryable<XMLTest> MyXmlHelper(int rating)
{
            throw new NotImplementedException("You can only call this function in a LINQ query");
}
```

Below is the linq query which I tried exactly as in the post, but not able to use the function and it throws error.

```
 var _dbCustomers = (from x in _context.XMLTests
                     where MyXmlHelper(1).Where(xh=> xh.XMLValue.Contains("1"))
                     select x);
```

Error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<XMLTest>' to 'bool
```

If I user Any(), I have the following error:

```
 var _dbCustomers = (from x in _context.XMLTests
                          where MyXmlHelper(1).Any(xh => xh.XMLValue.Contains("1"))
                          select x);
```

Error:

```
The specified method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[XMLTest] MyXmlHelper(Int32)' on the type 'CustomerRepository' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression because its return type does not match the return type of the function specified by its DbFunction attribute.
```

Can someone suggest on how to achieve this please?

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Comment: @marc_s, Yes, I am writing the sql query (FUNCTION) in sql server and I have updated the tags. Thanks for pointing at it :)

Comment: What error does it throw? `"You can only call this function in a LINQ query"`?

Comment: @Typist, it shows the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<XMLTest>' to 'bool'". I have also tried with Any() and I have the "Cannot be translated" error. Please check my updated question

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is caused by the return type of your stub function.

Can you check what the return type for your `FilterCustomersByRating` method is in your DbContext? I don't think it should be `XMLTest`. It should look similar to the code below:

```
[EdmFunction("TestingDbEntities", "FilterCustomersByRating")]
public virtual IQueryable<FilterCustomersByRating_Result> FilterCustomersByRating(Nullable<int> rating)
{
    var ratingParameter = rating.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("Rating", rating) :
        new ObjectParameter("Rating", typeof(int));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this)
    .ObjectContext
    .CreateQuery<FilterCustomersByRating_Result>("[TestingEntities]
        .[FilterCustomersByRating](@Rating)", ratingParameter);
}
```

In this case, the return type of the stub function would be of type `FilterCustomersByRating_Result` which is class auto-generated when you add the `FilterCustomersByRating` Table-valued function to your edmx file.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FilterCustomersByRating] 
    (@Rating int) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
    SELECT XMLTest.*
    FROM XMLTest
    CROSS APPLY XMLValue.nodes('//MetaData') N(C)
    where N.C.value('Rating[1]', 'int')=@Rating
GO
```

With this in mind your stub function should be return `IQueryable<FilterCustomersByRating_Result>`
i.e.

```
[EdmFunction("TestingDbEntities", "FilterCustomersByRating")]
public static IQueryable<FilterCustomersByRating_Result> MyXmlHelper(int rating)
{ 
    throw new NotImplementedException("You can only call this function in a LINQ query");
}
```

you can the use it as shown below:

```
var dbCustomers = (from x in _context.XMLTests
                   where MyXmlHelper(1).Any(xh => xh.XMLValue.Contains("1"))
                   select x);
```

Please note that while this will work it will return all `Customers`. You might need to modify the `FilterCustomersByRating` function to accept the`CustomerID` and `rating`.

Give it a try.

**EDIT**

In addition to the above, when defining the `MyXmlHelper` [EdmFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.edmfunctionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), make sure that the spelling of the `FunctionName` and `NamespaceName` is correct. In my case, the `FunctionName` is `FilterCustomersByRating` and `NamespaceName` is `TestingEntities` which match the values in the auto-generated DBContext class.

```
// </auto-generated code>
public partial class TestingEntities : DbContext
{
    public TestingEntities()
        : base("name=TestingEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<XMLTest> XMLTests { get; set; }

    [EdmFunction("TestingEntities", "FilterCustomersByRating")]
    public virtual IQueryable<FilterCustomersByRating_Result> FilterCustomersByRating(Nullable<int> rating)
    {
        var ratingParameter = rating.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("Rating", rating) :
            new ObjectParameter("Rating", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this)
        .ObjectContext
        .CreateQuery<FilterCustomersByRating_Result>("[TestingEntities]
            .[FilterCustomersByRating](@Rating)", ratingParameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: though I have the return type as "FilterCustomersByRating_Result" , I am still getting the same error "The specified method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[FilterCustomersByRating_Result] MyXmlHelper(Int32)' on the type 'CustomerRepository' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression because its return type does not match the return type of the function specified by its DbFunction attribute."

Comment: @Prasad 1. Check and make sure you are using .Any LINQ function.  2. Double check the spelling of your EdmFuntion namespace and funtionName and make sure they are both correct. In my tests changing `[EdmFunction("TestingDbEntities", "FilterCustomersByRating")]` to `[EdmFunction("TestingDbEntities", "FilterCustomersByRatingWRONGSPELLING")]` results in the same error as you are getting. What is the name of your `DbContext`?

Comment: @Prasad I've edited the answer to add more information. Let me know how you go.

Comment: I was using Store namespace. After changing it to the namespace of the DBContext, it shows the error "Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of like function."

Comment: Below is the SQL it generates on running the LINQ(which throws the above error): SELECT 
    [Extent1].[XMLId] AS [XMLId], 
    [Extent1].[XMLValue] AS [XMLValue]
    FROM [dbo].[XMLTest] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[FilterXmlByRating](1) AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent2].[XMLValue] LIKE N'%1%'
    )

Comment: Does the error come up when you run the SQL statement on SSMS? Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471537/search-xml-with-a-like-or-similar-full-search-operation) link. Is suggests casting you column to `nvarchar(max)` before passing it to `like`. Does that help?

Comment: Yes. This gives error in SSMS also. It works fine on casting nvarchar(max). But can you please suggest on how to achieve this in LINQ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56567/discussion-between-jamleck-and-prasad).

Answer (score 2):

#### First error

`where` clause in your queries needs to evaluate to a `bool` value.

`MyXmlHelper(1).Where(xh=> xh.XMLValue.Contains("1"))` will give a record of type `System.Linq.IQueryable<XMLTest>` and not `bool`. You need to come up with a expression which will return a `bool` value.

#### Second error

Same is applicable to second error - change your where clause to get `bool` value from the expression.

Comment: I am not sure on how to use the DbFunctions in the LINQ where clause. I did as per the other SO post(referred in my question), but still no luck. Any help on this?

Comment: You database function returns table, does it have CustomerId column?

Comment: Yes. It has the CustomerId as primary key.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FilterCustomersByRating] 
(@Rating int) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
SELECT XMLTest.*
FROM XMLTest
CROSS APPLY XMLValue.nodes('//MetaData') N(C)
where N.C.value('Rating', 'int') LIKE '<Rating>'.@Rating.'</Rating>'
GO
```

Change "=" to "LIKE". Don't know what N(C) is, cross apply, or N.C.value(), but using = instead of LIKE often gives me trouble. Its trying to cross evaluate ints/bools with strings, and for strings like "1" you should use LIKE